# Is there a nuke command in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there a command that destroys everything (trees hills) within a certain radius? I want to create an online world but I always seem to have the spawnpoint in a bunch of trees. Is there like a /nuke command or something of that nature?

Comment: You'd be better off using a world editor like MCEdit to do this.

Comment: You can try starting with a superflat world and use the initial spawn chunk as a base file for the server (non-superflat)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

<s>**No.** At least, not in vanilla Minecraft.</s> **Sort of.** You can use a series of `/fill` commands to do the job. It's a little limited, but you can do it.

Let's say you want a 100x100(ish) completely flat area. Stand in one spot (the center) and use the following commands:

```
/fill ~ ~ ~ ~50 ~10 ~50 minecraft:air
/fill ~ ~ ~ ~50 ~10 ~-50 minecraft:air
/fill ~ ~ ~ ~-50 ~10 ~50 minecraft:air
/fill ~ ~ ~ ~-50 ~10 ~-50 minecraft:air
```

You can also do just one of those, standing on a corner of the desired area, but make sure you have the correct X and Z directions. Also keep in mind that the `/fill` command can only do 32,768 blocks at a time, so if you want to use just one command, you're going to be very limited in what you can do.

A slightly simpler approach would be to use MCEdit. There, you can just plop the world in a level editor, flatten out your area, and not even need to mess with it. But if you want to do it in-game, that option is out there too.

Or, if starting over is an option, there are plenty of other random seeds out there.

Answer (score 4):

While that is a novel hypothetical solution to starting with a seed you don't like, it is much, *much* easier to just try again or find a pre-tried seed. Just delete and try again – it is vanishingly unlikely that you will start in a forest every single game in your life.

Regardless, there is no "nuke" command in the [list of commands](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands). Even if there was, or you added one with a mod, there isn't one that won't also blow a giant hole in the land that would make the spawn unsuitable for falling/caves/lava reasons.

There are plenty of [seeds shared online](http://www.minecraftseeds.info/), and not every world starts you in forest. The last two I tried were `Westeros` and `westeros` (yes, I've been reading a bunch of ASoIaF lately) – the former starts you beside a desert village with hills, river, forest, and taiga nearby, and the latter starts you on an island with one tree near some other islands and is excellent for a waterworld survival challenge. Those are evidence that not every seed starts you in the woods.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this execute command:

> /execute @e ~ ~ ~ /summon PrimedTnt ~ ~20 ~ {Fuse:60}

Try using the command **MULTIPLE** times in quick succession. Then there's **MASS DESTRUCTION!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!**

Source:  [MASS DESTRUCTION!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pd42JfWM0jc/%22MASS%20DESTRUCION%22)

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to go modless your best option is just flint and steel then maybe do some mining and by the time come back up there should be a good clearing other than a few tree blocks/

Comment: Fire doesn't spread as easily as it used to. A "forest fire" now only burns down a couple of trees.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Doing /gamerule doFireTick false will spread fire indefinitely.

Comment: @Timtech Really? I haven't tested it, but I was under the impression that it *disabled* fire ticks, which would disable fire spreading entirely.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie It's dependent on difficulty. /gamerule doFireTick false won't work at all, but Hard difficulty would. The hills part, however...

Comment: I think it would be really good if they added some kind of incendiary tnt that set blocks on fire, it would probably be banned on most servers instantly but it'd be fun

Comment: @SevenSidedDie That's also what I thought, but apprently it lets fire spread indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

Use a repeating command block and type in the command:

```
/summon tnt 0 4 0
```

Then place a redstone block next to the command block

Answer (score 0):

You can do `/execute at @a run fill ~ ~ ~ ~50 ~10 ~50 minecraft:air`
(for CommandBlocks)